# Finding specific string in an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, enumerate

I'm trying to get a specific String out of a huge txt-file, I converted into an array.

```
ROI = open('Patient_1.txt','r')
 a  = np.loadtxt(ROI,dtype=str,delimiter='\n')

 b  = np.array([i for i,item in enumerate(a) if "//  Beginning of ROI: PTV" in item])
```

The only and imense Problem is, that the output of **b** (index of string in array) does NOT fit with the index where this string is for real (e.g. Output: 71234 vs. Index in array: 71238).

Txt-File:

```
   71231             vertices={
   71232  };  // End of vertices for mean mesh
   71233                        triangles={
   71234  };  // End of triangles for mean mesh
   71235  }; // End of mean_mesh 
   71236         }; // End of ROI Haut
   71237 //-----------------------------------------------------
   71238 //  Beginning of ROI: PTV
   71239 //-----------------------------------------------------
   71240  roi={
   71241            name: PTV
```

And I need the exact position of that keyword in the array.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. This includes  a small snippet of your `Patient_1.txt`, that shows your faulty indexing.

Comment: I just added a abstract of the textfile, I hope it's comprehensible.

Comment: Is it possible that you have some lines that are `\r\n` terminated?

Comment: So `enumerate` increases for every line it reads from the file (starting at `0`). I am not sure how your line numbers work in the file, are they auto generated? Because I assume that there are some places that do not contain a line break (`\n`), hence the enumerate won't increase but your file numbering might increase.

Comment: Personally, if you are only looking for the logical line number of the FILE, I would use python native file operators with the [universal newline](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/)

Comment: Notice that empty lines will be thrown away when reading the data. Thus you might not end up having the same indices.

Comment: probably you should consider other command line options eg perl, sed, grep etc. if you using perl you can consider doing `perl -ne "m/\/\/  Beginning of ROI: PTV/  && print \"$.\n\"" Patient_1.txt`